# Firebase Query Returning Nil When Given Parameter

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionview

Im using this function to return the top 9 results in a data set in firebase. The array is then suppose to populate data fro a collection view. However when I go try to segue to the VC I get error "Index out of range".

```
    var userHighlights = [Post]()
func loadUserHighlightPosts(_ userID: String, update: @escaping() -> Void) {
   STORAGE_REF.child(userID).queryOrdered(byChild: "likes").queryLimited(toLast: 9).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let post = Post(postID: snap.key, postData: snap.value as! Dictionary<String,Any>)
            self.userHighlights.insert(post, at: 0)
            update()
        }
        if snapshot.childrenCount == 0 {
            update()
        }
    })
}
```

However, when I run the same function for the current user, using a different reference, everything works fine.

```
    var highlights = [Post]()
func loadCurrentUserHighlightPosts(_  update: @escaping() -> Void) {
    currentUserHighlightHandle = CURRENT_USER_STORAGE_REF.queryOrdered(byChild: "likes").queryLimited(toLast: 9).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let post = Post(postID: snap.key, postData: snap.value as! Dictionary<String, Any>)
            self.highlights.insert(post, at: 0)
            update()
        }
        if snapshot.childrenCount == 0 {
            update()
        }
    })
}
```

I am using prepareforsegue() to pass over the user's UID that is used in the functions parameter however the app continues to crash. Any help would be appreciated in advance, thanks!

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the index out of range error?

Comment: In cellForItemAt: let post = Database.data.userHighlights[indexPath.row]